# Star Trek Voyager shuttle conundrum

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In DS9 shuttles seem to be a-dime-a-dozen. They get destroyed on and off screen so many times that I've lost count. They then get replaced pretty fast.

Voyager only has two shuttles as far as I can tell. But they get damaged, crash land almost every other episode, get taken by the Kazon, etc.

- One was taken by Kazon when Chakotay was taken prisoner.
- One was destroyed. (Sometime in Season 2 or 3)
- One crash-landed but Tuvok seemingly repaired it with the power of Hollywoodism.

etc.
EDIT:

Not interested in how many Voyager has as this answer can be infinite. Intrepid can hold 2 but we see many, many more.

So my question/s are **how many Shuttles get destroyed in the show (on or off screen) and do they just replicate more when they lose them?**

Comment: I imagine that's among the reasons why Janeway had to ration replicator use and institute a central kitchen/mess hall for food: they're running the replicators full-time making ship and shuttle parts.

Comment: Shuttles are nothing. Photon torpedoes are the real mystery. In the beginning it is stated explicitly that they cannot create photon torpedoes and that they have to make do with the 38 they have. Over the course of seven seasons they fire at least 123. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIGxMENwq1k

Comment: The photon question was in relation to the amount of Anti Matter they had.
It was a stupid story point, like the coffee nebula, as every warp civilisation would have available antimatter (FFS Nelix was brought on board for that very reason, of trade)

Comment: @Hans: If everybody took me at my word for everything I said seven years ago, I'd look like a right liar! Things change.

Comment: @Zommuter please read the last sentence it is even bolded out.

Comment: So? Did you read the linked question? Its title may not convey it (neither is yours very descriptive, if I may be so frank), but the body states _"I have lost track of the number of times a shuttle has been destroyed."_ and also asks for those. Not that I didn't also upvote your question, since the other one is a non-trivial dupe-candidate

Comment: I've never watched the show, did the Voyager never get resupplied? Ever?  Seems unlikely to me that they'd never once in 7 years stop at a space dock of some kind.

Comment: There would stop at alien space docks from time to time but they were so far away from home they wouldn't get native equipment.

Comment: "... Tuvok seemingly repaired it with the power of Hollywoodism." The technical term for that is ***handwavium***.

Answer (score 8):

At least ten, [according to this page](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/inconsistencies-voy.htm):

> - Destroyed by Kazon vessel
> - Destroyed in temporal rift
> - Cannibalized by ex-Borg
> - Destroyed or vanished in the course of Kes' evolution
> - Destroyed by Caatati vessel
> - Given to telepathic refugees (2)
> - Crashed on planet in high gravity region, salvage impossible
> - Assimilated by the Borg
> - Destroyed by energy barrier

The list on the page also includes the episode names where this happened.

That page also lists seven more that were probably lost, and also notes the inconsistencies WRT the shuttle types. And the numerous other inconsistencies of the show.